# Message communication between Django and Twisted

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, twisted

I've created remote objects monitoring application.

**Application description**: Twisted communicates with remote controllers and then saves measured data to database via "adbapi". Django is used as web interface.

**Problem**: Django uses models for database access. Twisted uses raw SQL queries, generates alerts and other before save operations. I want to move all logic from Twisted to Django. So that Twisted will be layer between remote controllers and Django. Django will use models and save measured data, perform various operations and so on.

**Question**: Best way to organize communication between Twisted and Django? Two-way communication bus between them. At the moment I've 3 options:

1. Perform http POST request via getPage from twisted.web.client and on other side handle it by Django.
2. Use RabbitMQ and pika module as transport on Twisted side. Use Django-standalone app as daemon on other side.

I believe that there should be a better solution than my offer.

P.S.: [image: base structure]

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to my own question:** for now I've used RabbitMQ as a transport. On **twisted** side used **pika module** via this [adapter](https://github.com/pika/pika/blob/master/docs/examples/twisted_example.rst). On **django** side I created a django standalone script as a daemon. Daemon endlessly waiting for new messages from RabbitMQ via pika module.

Please, let me know if there is a better solution.

Comment: It is. With the queue you can scale this horizontally and avoid hard dependencies.  We use queues heavily to communicate between Django, twisted, graphite, log stash, elastic search and so on.  "Message for Storage, Database for History"

Comment: Thanks for your response. By the way: is it good practice to use Django standalone script as a daemon?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Django management commands were meant for that. Just make sure you run them under superviserd or some other daemon manager.